# C# get data with name attribute in XML

Tags: c#, xml

There are some fields on my xml document which are same value but under different name. I want to select the value of "Error" on this xml document and so want to display "deger2". Also I want to display "deger5" How can I do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Database xmlns="http://www.example.com/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Datas>
  <Data name="sMsg" access="private" xsi:type="collection" type="string">
     <Value key="Cycle" value="deger1" />
     <Value key="Error" value="deger2" />
     <Value key="Info" value="deger3" />
     <Value key="Jog" />
     <Value key="Warning" />
  </Data>
  <Data name="tTabla" access="private" xsi:type="array" type="tabla" size="1">
     <Value key="Cycle" value="deger4" />
     <Value key="Error" value="deger5" />
     <Value key="Info" value="deger6" />
     <Value key="Jog" />
     <Value key="Warning" />
  </Data>
 </Datas>
</Database>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take the xml namespace into considiration. Using Linq to Xml

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring); //XDocument.Load(filename)
XNamespace ns = "http://www.example.com/2";

var errors = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "Value") //<-- See the usage of ns
                .Where(d => (string)d.Attribute("key") == "Error")
                .Select(d => (string)d.Attribute("value"))
                .ToList();
```

**EDIT**

> Is there any way to select like this: select error value where Data name="tTabla"?

```
var errors = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "Data")
                .First(d => (string)d.Attribute("name") == "tTabla")
                .Descendants(ns + "Value") 
                .First(d => (string)d.Attribute("key") == "Error")
                .Attribute("value")
                .Value;
```

**EDIT2**

You can also use XPATH

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.CreateNavigator().NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.example.com/2");

var errors = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//ns:Data[@name='tTabla']/ns:Value[@key='Error']", nsmgr)
                    .Attribute("value")
                    .Value;
```

Comment: Is there any way to select like this: select error value where Data name="tTabla"?

Comment: Thats true but what happens if key equals to a number like 0,1 or etc. It is work for string like "error" but not for "0","1","2". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Key can not be equal to a number, attributes in xml *must be* a string. So if it is `key="0"` it should work.

Comment: It didn't worked for key="0" it gives this error:"Sequence contains no matching element"  But this key is exist.

Comment: @tebdilikiyafet I don't know your *real* xml, your *real* code and what you are doing. I think I answered your *original* question. Now it is your time to make it work.

Comment: My question is just like above. I didn't asked the all details to be clear. Only some keys are like this key="0". Your answer is very helpful for me thanks. If you help on this problem I will be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

U can also use XPath to select them:

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes("//Data/Value[@key="Error"]");
```